# Operators on an Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, orthogonal-matrices, self-adjoint-operators, normal-operator

> Let $A, B$ be self-adjoint positive operators, $C, D$ be orthogonal
>   operators on an Euclidean space, and $AC = DB$.
>
> Prove that $A=B \Leftrightarrow AC$ is normal.

I know many properties of self-adjoint and orthogonal operators and tried to apply them but with no success. Could you please help me?

Comment: I solved the second part, but the first one is still open. Do you have a source for this exercise?

Comment: @Jan, the source is a task book (in Russian) where no commentaries or hints are given. Can you please share you solution for the second part? I still have no idea...

Comment: If it helps you, I could post you a partial answer with the proof of the equivalence. You also could split the question into two questions (as it is normally also recommended on this site, i.e., ask a new one) and then I could answer the "second part".

Comment: @Jan, I splitted it. You can now answer here.

Comment: @Jan, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $AC$ is normal iff $(AC)^\ast (AC) = (AC)(AC)^\ast$. Since $AC = DB$ holds, this is equivalent to $(DB)^\ast (DB) = (AC)(AC)^\ast$. This holds iff $B^\ast D^\ast DB = ACC^\ast A$. But $C$ and $D$ are orthogonal, hence it follows that $B^\ast B = A A^\ast$. Since $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint, this simplifies to $A^2 = B^2$. Finally, this implies $A = B$ since $A^2$ and $B^2$ are positive and therefore have a unique square root.